# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteErrorエラーでServerへのデプロイに失敗する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano

デプロイしたいがエラーが発生する。
ちなみに、`ssh 127.0.0.1`を実行したところ、`ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`のエラーメッセージが発生する。

何が原因なのかわからないです。教えてもらえないでしょうか？

#### 環境

Rails 5, Unicorn, Nginx, Capistrano, Ubuntu 14.04

#### 実行したコマンド

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy:check
```

#### エラー内容

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
<Thread:0x00007fa5e9275448@/Users/takashi_kageyama/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/takashi_kageyama/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/takashi_kageyama/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as ops@vagrant.local: Authentication failed for user ops@127.0.0.1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ops@vagrant.local: Authentication failed for user ops@127.0.0.1


Caused by:
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ops@127.0.0.1

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh 127.0.0.1`と実行すると以下のエラーが発生するということは、sshdが
起動されていないかインストールされていないと思います。

```
    ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

(インストールして)起動することで事象解消しないでしょうか?

Comment: "ssh"をインストールしましたが、解消しませんでした。gemで"capistrano"をインストールした時に"sshkit"がインストールされいたようですが・・・。ちなみに、sshの起動状況の確認をしようとしましたが、よく分かりませんでした。

Comment: やっぱり、"ssh"関連が問題となっているみたいなので、"unix"関連を勉強してみます。・・・問題を解決する方向性は、合っているのかな？

Comment: sshdが起動しているかどうか確認するのは必要なので、方向性としてはあっていると思います。

Comment: ありがとございます。もう少し、絞り込んだ質問できるよう勉強してみます。